# Should a peer dependency be added in both peerDependencies and dependencies in package.json?

Tags: npm, peer-dependencies

I have a library that uses npm packages that I want as peer dependencies where the app would have to install them (eg. axios, react, react-dom). The goal is to avoid having libraries add to overall bundle size of the app.

Should I add these only under "peerDependencies" or is it okay to add it to "dependencies" as well? I thought it would be good to remove them from "dependencies" just to be sure that they don't get installed on top of what the app already has. However, if I exclude them from "dependencies" then my library tests start to fail because they are only peer dependencies and npm didn't install them.

I thought of installing them manually or adding them as devDependencies just for the purpose of running tests, but I think there has to be a better way. If I add both "dependencies" and "peerDependencies" does npm actually ignore the same dependencies in peerDepenedencies?